# Keepass Auto-Type in browser without desktop app?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, keepass

I'm using Keepass with a kdbx file in Dropbox. Is there a browser extension for Chrome that supports Auto-Type in the browser without an underlying desktop app?

What I want: I get a login screen in some browser to a web app in some intranet that I access via RDP.
I can't install the desktop app inside that RDP environment.
I can only access the web app when I'm on the intranet.

What I want: a Keepass extension (or a how-to), that lets me hit a key combination in the browser, that auto-types my credentials in the browser tab, that does not require the desktop app to be present.

Is there such a thing?

So far, I've looked at a few things.

[Keeweb](https://app.keeweb.info/) requires the desktop app (or I have a hard time understanding the [documentation](https://github.com/keeweb/keeweb/wiki/Browser%20AutoFill)).

Both [KeePassHttp-Connector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keepasshttp-connector/dafgdjggglmmknipkhngniifhplpcldb) and [KeePassHTTP](https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp/) require the Desktop app, please CMIIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have KeePass here and have it on all my computers via the Desktop App.

The apps you point to require the desktop app, as do numerous other KeePass apps for IOS and Android.

So the answer to your question is:  Desktop App / Database required for KeePass.

You can consider Last Pass which is entirely different and all mobile. I still like KeePass as overall better for my needs.

Comment: Thanks for confirming I have not overlooked anything. Another alternative would be to use the browser password safe, but it would be all or nothing and I also have Keepass on all my computers and my phone, and I still like it too.

Comment: I like KeePass and Last Pass was too limited for me even though it goes on all devices including mobile devices

Comment: Also, I do not think you missed anything.